# Restoring expanded responsive navbar sub-menu creates scrollbar Bootstrap 3.0.2

Tags: css

I know this issue was covered in another post but his fix didn't work for me since I have a drop down sub-menu. Is there away just to make the menu collapse when switching between the two so the scroll bars don't appear?

**Submenu css used**

[http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/multi-level-dropdown-menu-bs3][1]

**Fixed Tired**

> This is a known issue in 3.0.2
>   (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/11243)
>
> A workaround:
>
> .navbar-collapse.in {
>       overflow-y: visible; } Demo: http://bootply.com/96924
>
> Skelly
>   [Restoring expanded responsive navbar menu creates scrollbar in Bootstrap 3.0.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20230091/restoring-expanded-responsive-navbar-menu-creates-scrollbar-in-bootstrap-3-0-2)

**My CSS Menu**

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header" >
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">Chesapeake Controls Inc.</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div style="display: inline-block;" class="pull-right">
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">


                        <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Capabilities<b class="caret"></b></a>
             <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                   <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a href="#">Building Automation Systems</a>
                   <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                   <li><a href="#">Products</a> </li>
                   <li><a href="#">Services</a> </li>
                   </ul>
             </li>

             <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a href="#">HVAC Service</a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                   <li><a href="#">Maintenance</a> </li>
                   <li><a href="#">Installation</a> </li>
                   </ul>
             </li>


                </ul>
            </li>



               <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Projects<b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Building Automation</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">HVAC</a></li>


                </ul>
            </li>



            <li><a href="#contact">Careers</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>

            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Login<b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Customer Portal</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">PPS Maintenance</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">File Server</a></li>

                </ul>
            </li>


          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div><!-- /.container -->
      </div>
    </nav>
```